# Set keyboard shortcut for a WPF Button with no text on it

Tags: wpf

I have a button that looks like this:

```
<Button Margin="3,0,2,0" Command="{Binding AddCommand}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Image Width="24" Stretch="Uniform"
            Source="pack://application:,,,/MyProj;component/Images/Add.png"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

It does not have any text on it.  But if it did, it would have this inside the StackPanel:

```
<Label Margin="2,0,1,0" Content="_Add" />
```

This would allow Alt+A to be the keyboard command for the button.

Is there a way to set this without having text on the button?

NOTE the AddCommand is a DelegateCommand (and it needs to be).  So the RoutedCommand way of setting keyboard shortcuts will not work.  (Not unless there is a way to retrofit a DelegateCommand as a RoutedCommand.)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is enough to make it work:

```
<Button Margin="3,0,2,0" Command="{Binding AddCommand}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Image Width="24" Stretch="Uniform"
            Source="pack://application:,,,/MyProj;component/Images/Add.png"/>
     <Label Margin="0" Width="0" Opacity="0" Content="_Add" />
   </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Bit of a hack as it adds a Label that is not visible.  But it works good enough.